# Sharepoint user profile access

Tags: 2013

New to SharePoint.

I have configured FQDN for my SharePoint site (test.com). The problem is when i click on someone's profile, it redirects me to local server URL (SPServer/my/person.aspx) not the FQDN url (test.com/my/person.aspx).

Comment: What does your [Alternative Access Mapping](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sharepoint_strategery/archive/2013/05/25/alternate-access-mappings-explained.aspx) say? Preferably the default mapping

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Navigate to the User Profile Service Application, Setup My Sites, and review the My Site Host location.  You will want this to be a FQDN path to the site collection setup as the MySite Host.